# My lex program isn't working

Tags: c, lex, lexical-analysis

```
/* def*/
%{
#include <stdio.h>
int vowelCount = 0;
int consonantCount = 0;
%}

/*RULES*/
%%
[aeiouAEIOU] {vowelCount = vowelCount + 1;}
[A-Za-z][^aeiouAEIOU] {consonantCount = consonantCount + 1;}
%%

/*fct*/
int main(void)
{
    yylex();
    printf ("il y a %d voyelles",vowelCount);
    printf ("il y a %d consonnes",consonantCount);
    return 0;
}
```

This is my first ever lex program. I want it to count how many vowels and how many consonants are in the source..

I'm having 2 problems:

1. I don't get the `printf` after yylex until after doing Ctrl+C, and stopping execution. so yylex isn't letting any instructions after it, execute unless I quit stop the entire execution
2. I'm not geting the correct numbers.
   For example for "good",
   I got 1 vowel and 1 consonant instead of 2 vowels and 2 consonants.

What do I need to do to fix these problems?

Comment: Please supply more details. I'm using Bision v3.0.4 and it won't even compile.

Comment: @devnull: "doesn't compile" or "doesn't link"? For the latter, add `-lfl` to the link command. (Needed for `yywrap`, which is not explicitly defined by OP's file.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your lex rules never return, so the scan will continue until the end of input is reached. If you are providing input from the console, you need to send an end of input by typing Control-D (linux/mac) / Control-Z (windows) at the beginning of a line.
2. Your first rule matches any vowel. Your second rule matches any letter followed by a non-vowel. So the matches in `good` are:

   - <kbd>g</kbd> Default rule
   - <kbd>o</kbd> rule 1 (vowel)
   - <kbd>od</kbd> rule 2 (consonant)

   The newline character which presumably follows `good` will also be matched by the default rule.
3. Note that there is a difference between "anything which is not a vowel" and "a consonant". For example, <kbd>!</kbd> is not a vowel.
4. The lex default rule (which matches exactly one character if nothing else matches the input at that point) prints the character to stdout. That is almost certainly not what you want, so you should add your own fallback rule which does nothing.

Comment: how do i solve this then ? .. i'm so sorry i started learning lex because of compilation module in uni, but they don't teach us anything about (just compilation theory). and do you recommend any good tutos or pdfs other than the lex website

Comment: @hammi: the chapters in the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual) on Patterns and Matching are important. Other than that, the best reference I know of is the O'Reilly book on Flex and Bison; hopefully your University library has a copy.

Comment: Also, the `-d` option to flex is very helpful to see what is going on.